# How to get the external ip in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I looked for some code that will help me to get the ip that the iPhone connect with.

I find this one:

```
- (NSString *)getIPAddress
{
    NSString *address = @"error";
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;

    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0)
    {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL)
        {
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
            {
                // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"])
                {
                    // Get NSString from C String
                    address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
                }
            }

            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }

    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);

    return address;
}
```

but the problem is that he get me this ip
10.0.0.1

How to get the external ip?

Comment: What sort of IP address are you expecting? The device is likely to be going through a WiFi or 3G network, etc. hence you're not likely to be able to retrieve any form of meaningful "external" IP address.

Comment: Middaparka is right - from the device's viewpoint, 10.0.0.1 *is* its external IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to get your internet ip address from code is to use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

For the URL you can use: 
    http://www.whatismyip.com/m/mobile.asp
or 
   http://checkip.dyndns.com/

Just parse the return data and you have your external ip address.

Comment: I like it. Not so much for prod apps but GREAT for debugging. +1

Comment: Unless you have like 10m DAU and call this every launch, then you really cost WhatIsMyIP.com A LOT of money in bandwidth for something that could be a local function. :o

Answer (score 2):

Check Apple's [PortMapper](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PortMapper/Listings/PortMapper_h.html), does exactly what you want.

As of iOS7 this is irrelevant.

Comment: The PortMapper is for "Runtime requirements: Mac OS X 10.5"

Comment: I am using it for my iPhone app.

Comment: Nothing major that I remember. Works flawlessly, 3G or Wifi.

Comment: If you edit your answer with some additional information, I can remove my down vote from your answer.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing to add. PortMapper does the job flawlessly. End of story. Down vote if you like.

Comment: Give´s me null for the public ip Adress on iOS 7

Comment: Same for me @chrizstone

Comment: Irrelevant for iOS 7+

Comment: what do you mean by "As of iOS7 this is irrelevant."?

Comment: That's the solution. @ssteinberg +1

Comment: It looks like PortMapper pings the DNS server for the IP address it sees... If the DNS server is internal to your network I believe PortMapper will give you the wrong IP.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the example in my second Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266428/accessing-ip-address-with-nshost/3301169#3301169).

In a nutshell it uses *http://www.dyndns.org/cgi-bin/check_ip.cg*i to get the extenal I.P

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but https://api4.ipify.org or http://api4.ipify.org returns nothing else but the external IPv4 address of your connection. Code:

```
NSURL *ipifyUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api4.ipify.org/"];
NSString *externalAddr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:ipifyUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

https://api6.ipify.org returns the external IPv6 address and https://api64.ipify.org either the IPv4 or the IPv6 address. Simple documentation can be found at https://www.ipify.org