# Get the WAN IP in the iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, networking

So I need to retrieve the user's WAN IP from within the app I am building. I saw this answer here: 
[iPhone/iPad/OSX: How to get my IP address programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072989/iphone-ipad-osx-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically)

But this only returns the user's IP address in the local network.

By what means can I know the user's WAN IP from within the app?

Comment: You'll probably need to query an online IP service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the external ip in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450621/how-to-get-the-external-ip-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get your wap ip address is to use `NSURLConnection`.

For the URL you can use: http://www.whatismyip.com/m/mobile.asp or http://www.dyndns.org/cgi-bin/check_ip.cgi

Just parse the return data and you have your external ip address. A complete implementation is shown [here](http://ios-programming.blogspot.gr/2011/03/find-external-ip-address-in-iphone-sdk.html). It is not the most efficient way, but it works.

Comment: If you copy an answer, at least credit the [original](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5450813) ;)