# get iP location of the iOS device programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to get the ip location of the iOS device programmatically, how do I get it? for example: I should get India/westbengal.'

Comment: For getting device's WAN IP check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5450813/653513