# NSHost "currentHost" not recognized

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nshost

i'd like to use this code to know my ip, but i got 2 warnings that i can't fix for now. I also found this post : [Accessing IP Address with NSHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266428/accessing-ip-address-with-nshost)

but i just wanted to understand why this code does not work, if anyone has an answer?

here's my code :

> ```
>       -(NSString*)getAddress {
>             NSString *iphone_ip = [NSString initWithString:@"127.0.0.1"];
>             NSHost* myhost =[NSHost currentHost];
>             if (myhost)
>             {
>                 NSString *ad = [myhost address];
>                 if (ad)
>                     strcpy(iphone_ip,[ad cStringUsingEncoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]);
>             }
>             return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",iphone_ip]; 
>         }
> ```

the first warning is on :

> NSHost* myhost =[NSHost currentHost]

, saying that currentHost is not recognised. 
The second one is on

> NSString *ad = [myhost address];

" incompatible obj-c types initializing 'struct NSData *", expected 'struct NString*" "

I can imagine the second warning might disappear when the first warning is resolved...

Thanks for your help

Paul

Comment: Whenever you have a static string that needs no modification do not use any NSString methods just store the string! `NSString *iphone_ip = @"127.0.0.1";` and next never call a method that begins with init without calling alloc first, I am sure have a compiler warnings for that as well since it is not a class method.

Comment: @Joe, thanks yes it makes sense i wrote it a bit too fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the documentation here, it's documented under the OS X library.

[NSHost](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHost_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

It's actually a private API on the iPhone. You should still be able to use it, but you'll get compiler warnings.

If you need to find out your IPAddress, you can use a NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection using this URL: [WhatIsMyIP API](http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp)

That page is there specifically for programmers to use. They ask that you ping it no more than once every 300 seconds. You can find a FAQ here: [FAQ](http://www.whatismyip.com/faq/automation.asp)

Comment: Along with compiler warnings you will get the boot from Apple when you go to submit it to the App store.

Comment: @thomashw thanks , the thing is, i took this example from appsamuck.com , it seems that a lot of their code have several "depreciated" methods or just a code that does not work. Do you know what i could do to make the ip thing work?

Comment: @thomashw thanks, why nsURLConnection? i knew NSURL and NSURLRequest to load a url, but not nsURLConnection. Thanks for the links

Comment: The NSURLConnection lets you load the URL request. It'll allow you to get the response back from the server by implementing the delegate methods.