# App rejection issue 2.5: Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I got following message from app review team, now i am confused how to fix it and what is the problem exectly any help would be appreciated.

> 2.5
>
> We found that your app uses one or more non-public APIs, which is not
>   in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. The use of
>   non-public APIs is not permissible because it can lead to a poor user
>   experience should these APIs change.
>
> We found the following non-public API/s in your app:
>
> currentHost
>
> If you have defined methods in your source code with the same names as
>   the above-mentioned APIs, we suggest altering your method names so
>   that they no longer collide with Apple's private APIs to avoid your
>   application being flagged in future submissions.
>
> Additionally, one or more of the above-mentioned APIs may reside in a
>   static library included with your application. If you do not have
>   access to the library's source, you may be able to search the compiled
>   binary using "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings"
>   tool can output a list of the methods that the library calls and
>   "otool -ov" will output the Objective-C class structures and their
>   defined methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the
>   problematic code resides.
>
> We appreciate that you may have made the precautions in your code for
>   using non-public APIs, however, there is no way to accurately or
>   completely predict how an API may be modified and what effects those
>   modifications may have. For this reason, we do not permit the use of
>   non-public APIs in App Store apps.
>
> If there are no alternatives for providing the functionality your app
>   requires, we encourage you to file an enhancement request. Or, try
>   working with the Apple Developer Technical Support team to explore
>   alternative solutions.
>
> On occasion, there may be apps on the App Store that don't appear to
>   be in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. We work hard to
>   ensure that the apps on the App Store are in compliance and we try to
>   identify any apps currently on the App Store that may not be. It takes
>   time to identify these occurrences but another app being out of
>   compliance is not a reason for your app to be. For discrete code-level
>   questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical
>   Support. Please be sure to:
>
> - include the complete details of your rejection issues
> - prepare any symbolicated crash logs, screenshots, and steps to reproduce the issues for when the DTS engineer follows up.
>
> For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see
>   Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application
>   Crash Reports.
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please try testing the
>   workflow as described in
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/Testing Workflow
>   with Xcode's Archive feature".

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well the text is very clear, you are using a private API which is not allowed. If you don't use a private API then you have a method which has the same name as a private API, go and change that name and resubmit your app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is telling you **exactly** what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: The issue is with the method "currentHost", it might being used in your application somewhere. Thats why your application got rejected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys, let me search in code, and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using this method to get your current ip in your application. You can use other alternatives like in the link mentioned:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6535436/1111384

You can use this to get current ip.

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Yes, i am getting ip address for sure in the application, if i use your mentioned method then apple wont put any restriction again?

Comment: No.Its 3rd party API. In this the IP will be returned by that API. So Apple wont reject your app.

Comment: You only need to call "http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp" this URL address using URL Request & you will receive your IP address in a string in response. So there will be no issue of rejection due to private api call.